# SQL statement to linq lambda

Tags: linq, lambda

i have this sql statement : *Select FileURL from story where ActivityID = ' " listACt " ' ;*

How do i convert this to linq lambda?

i have this but its not working :

```
        public IList<Model.story> GetActivityList(int listAct)
     {

         IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();
         return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct).ToList().Select( a => a.FileURL).ToList();

     }
```

The error shows : Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<iStellarMobile.Model.story>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

EDIT ---------------------------

```
   protected void btnSort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dropListActivity.SelectedIndex > 0)
            gvStory.DataSource = daoStory.GetActivityList(Convert.ToInt32(dropListActivity.SelectedItem.Value));
        else
        {   }


        gvStory.DataBind();
    }
```

Error with the above code after using SWeko 's 2nd code :

The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'iStellarMobile.DAO.DAOStory.GetActivityList(int)' and 'iStellarMobile.DAO.DAOStory.GetActivityList(int)'

Comment: Return a `List<Model.story>`

Comment: Is it really ambiguous between two methods with the same name and signature? Btw, if `gvStory` is a GridView that should display stories, you might need my first code, not the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SWeko's got you covered as far as the first error you were seeing, but you should note that if you're looking to turn a "SQL statement to linq lambda", your query might not be doing what you expect. Assuming `context` is an Entity Framework context or similar, this:

```
IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();

return lstImages
    .Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct)
    .Select(a => a.FileURL)
    .ToList();
```

...executes a SQL statement selecting everything from the `stories` table on the first line, then executes your lambda in memory using Linq-to-objects. Consider changing it to this:

```
return context.stories
    .Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct)
    .Select(a => a.FileURL)
    .ToList();
```

...which will result in your lambda being converted into SQL which matches the statement you're after (*Select FileURL from story where ActivityID = ' " listACt " '*).

For your second error, the compiler is saying you have two methods with the same signature - `iStellarMobile.DAO.DAOStory.GetActivityList(int)` - find the two and change one so they're different.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring that you will return a (i)list of stories, but you are returning a list of FileURLs, which according to the error message, is a list of strings.

You could either do

```
public IList<Model.story> GetActivityList(int listAct)
{
  IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();
  return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct).ToList();
}
```

or

```
public IList<string> GetActivityList(int listAct)
{
  IList<Model.story> lstImages = context.stories.ToList();
  return lstImages.Where(c => c.ActivityID == listAct)
                  .Select( a => a.FileURL)
                  .ToList();
}
```

Comment: ActivityID field is an int column

Comment: Ok, than this will work, there are lots of quotes in the question text, that threw me off.

Comment: See my edit , i tried your code , it shows no error on the CRUD class side. but theres an error with the aspx.cs side.